# SharePoint server is too Slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

My sharepoint server is having the below s/w:

1. SP 2013 SP1 Std. version
2. SQL SERVER Std.Version with SP2
3. caml designer / builder
4. sharepoint designer 2013
5. workflow manager with refresh
6. search center is also configured
7. incremental crawling is enabled

UPDATE :
 H/W infor:
 my machine is having :

24 GB RAM

930 GB HARD DISK SPACE

IBM SYSTEM X 3630M4

INTEL  XEON R CPU 2.20  GHZ PROCESSOR

we have created some 20+ complex designer workflows in this machine as part of our requirement and nowadays   I am facing server slowness issue.
What may be the reason for this slowness? 
and is there any solution for this slowness?  I have restarted the server multiple times, still no help.

Am not able to even the load the custom aspx pages with JSOM code, in a fast manner. it s taking ages to load a form.

[image: SP-SERVER-CONTENTDB-SIZE]

Comment: Please provide the server hardware specifications as well in questions for reference. There are many factors that affect the server speed. As (may be) you have installed all in one server (standalone type) instead of 2,3, n-tier architecture. It may also affect your server performance. Search service also eats much resources in the server.

Comment: Delete unwanted logs in LOGS folder. Check the space on the your machine. For SharePoint server it requires minimum of 37 GB free space to operate it in right manner. As said in the above comment also check hardware specifications of your machine. Check size of RAM that you have used. Also see number of web applications that you have created. Delete the unwanted web applications those that are not in use.

Comment: have provided the  h/w server details I have deleted the logs files , for this, I already have a powershell script, that's executed as a windows scheduler, so   no problem with LOGS folder files. 37 GB free space in C drive?

Comment: Check event viewer and SharePoint databases size on Database Server

Comment: I suppose it's more a workflow or workflow managing problem than hardware, database or logging. Did you try to cut off the connection to the workflow manager? Did you install any CUs after you designed the workflows? And did you check the event viewer to observe whether there a traced workflow error on system level?

Comment: No, I didn't try to cut off the connection to WF manager. No, I didn't install any CUs after I designed the workflows.                                             Can you please throw some light on how to find out "traced workflow error"

Comment: am checking the SP CONTENT  DB size. Will update here soon. CAN I DELETE THE WSS_USAGE APPLN ?

Comment: IF I delete the wss_usageappln, is it possible to re-create ? either by powershell ?

Comment: are you using Antivirus? do they have the recommended exclusions? Also look at where your data center is relative to you, bandwidth, time zone differences between all the servers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is old question, i added some performance troubleshooting steps, which may be helpful. There are many reasons for the slowness. couple of them are:

- First thing, open the task manager and check which process is consuming too much memory and then try to fix that.
- As search configured on the same farm & incremental crawl also enabled, this may cause slowness in certain situations. Like, if crawl is running then server may be slow, [noderunner.exe](https://platinumdogs.me/2014/01/07/controlling-search-noderunner-memory-usage-in-sharepoint-2013/) is another culprit who consume most of the server resources.
- You have SQL server on the same server, make sure memory cap for the SQL sever otherwise it consume all available memory which make SharePoint life hard.
- disabled Antivirus or exclude your SharePoint folders from Scanning.
- If you have any other auditing software, i would disabled / uninstall as this is dev farm.
- enable the Developer dashbaord and check which component taking too much time on page loading.